# Screen locked after second SIAlertView message and popViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, svprogresshud, sialertview

When the request failed, `SIAlertView` shows error message then click the OK button of `SIAlertView`, popViewController working and there is no problem but when I tried second time and request failed, popViewController working again but there is gray and locked screen. The screen doesn't give any response.

How can I fix this problem?
By the way, I am using `SVProgressHUD` to show and hide loader.

```
self.showLoader()
showCardViewModel?.generateCard(success: { [weak self] (cardModel) in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    if let cardModel = cardModel {
        strongSelf.cardModel = cardModel
    }
    self?.cardInfoView.isHidden = false
    self?.bottomView.isHidden = false
    strongSelf.hideLoader()
}, failure: { [weak self] (error) in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    strongSelf.hideLoader()
    AlertHelper.showAlert(with: AlertType.error,
                             message: error.localizedDescription,
                             delegate: self)
})
```

Extension Method:

```
extension ShowCardVC: SIAlertViewDelegate {
    func alertView(_ alertView: SIAlertView!, clickedButtonAt buttonIndex: Int) {
        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this control into dismissAnimated method in `SIAlertView.m`

```
if ([SIAlertView sharedQueue].count >= 1) { [SIAlertView hideBackgroundAnimated:YES]; }
```